# Subdomain Is Redirected and Causing an Error Because www. is Added

Tags: php, web-development, apache, htaccess, no-www

On my site, say `example.com`, if I try to access `test.example.com`, Firefox automatically adds `www`. to `test.example.com`, making it `www.test.example.com`, which causes an error. However, if I visit a site like `my.ebay.com`, no `www.` is added so no error occurs. What's going on?

Just in case, my .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I looked through Firebug and it seems like Firefox doesn't even make an attempt to reach `test.example.com` before reverting to `www.test.example.com`.

One nuance I didn't realize until now. If I try to access the site using `test.example.com/`, the `www.` is added. If however that trailing slash is not there, then I am sent to the sub domain properly.

Comment: *What* error do you get?

Comment: Try pinging the address and see that it actually exists in DNS. Some browsers second guess if test.example.com does not resolve and try adding www for a second attempt.

Comment: I tried pinging the subdomain and I am able to reach it. As for the error I get, it reads "You tried to visit www.test.example.com, which is not loading."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yet Another Mod_Rewrite Issue - Firefox Adds www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270212/yet-another-mod-rewrite-issue-firefox-adds-www)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to manually adding the protocol prefix?

`http://test.example.com` won't get redirected.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*).example.com/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

In the future, look at this article: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/714016

Comment: But I'm trying to build a website for others and I don't want them to have to go through that. I just want my site to be like the other millions out there.

Comment: Try the updated htaccess

Comment: That fix would only work for one subdomain, I need it to work for all subdomains.

Comment: Actually, the updated .htaccess doesn't seem to fix it for any subdomains.

Comment: The issue still exists even with that updated .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

There's www automatically added in your url because you stated it in your htaccess rule.

Look at this part:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That mean to add www to your url when its not present.

Comment: This only matters if the ul just starts with example.com. test.example.com would not match tht rule

Comment: Yeah, if I remove the two lines you quoted from my .htaccess file I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a small glitch or something that was fixed by clearing the browser's history.